# is this a correct way of handling lots of routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, filter, routes

i have a template url called /monsters. and in the template, i have a sidebar

Sort by Type:

- Water
- Fire
- Earth
- Flying
- etc...

i was wondering what was the best way to route each of those? im guessing it would be good to have the urls such as

```
www.example.com/monsters/water
```

or

```
www.example.com/monsters/fire.
```

how should i go about doing that? on my routes.rb i thought of

```
match 'monsters/water',     to: 'monsters#water'
match 'monsters/fire',      to: 'monsters#fire'
match 'monsters/earth',     to: 'monsters#earth'
match 'monsters/flying',    to: 'monsters#flying'
```

etc...

but i feel like thats not a good way of doing. having a separate match going to a different action every time? could someone help me with the design? thorough and clear help would be much appreciated = )

thanks a bunch = )

or should i even be having separate links to begin with? should i be posting everything to my index action? i thought of using a form and using :post but thats already taken by my create action for monsters. currently on my index page (/monsters) its listing all of them because in my index action, i just do a

```
@monsters = Monster.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is:

```
resources :monsters, path: '/monsters/:category'
```

This will generate these routes:

```
named path   | verb   | route                                  | controller#action
             |        |                                        |
monsters     | GET    | /monsters/:category(.:format)          | monsters#index
monsters     | POST   | /monsters/:category(.:format)          | monsters#create
new_monster  | GET    | /monsters/:category/new(.:format)      | monsters#new
edit_monster | GET    | /monsters/:category/:id/edit(.:format) | monsters#edit
monster      | GET    | /monsters/:category/:id(.:format)      | monsters#show
monster      | PUT    | /monsters/:category/:id(.:format)      | monsters#update
monster      | DELETE | /monsters/:category/:id(.:format)      | monsters#destroy
```

And it will allow you to do things like:

```
/monsters/fire  => { controller: 'monsters', action: 'index', category: 'fire' }
/monsters/water => { controller: 'monsters', action: 'index', category: 'water' }
/monsters/earth/15 => { controller: 'monsters', action: 'show', category: 'earth', id: 15 }
```

Plus, you can still use named paths:

```
monsters_path('flying') => '/monsters/flying'
edit_monster_path('fire', 15) => '/monsters/fire/15'
```

And link to monsters like:

```
<%= link_to monster.name, monster_path(monster.category, monster.id) -%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify a generic route which accepts a variable segment, and use that to load the correct type of monster:

```
match "monsters/:category" => "monsters#index"

...

class MonstersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @monsters = Monster.find_by_category(params[:category])
  end
end
```

You could make the `:category` segment optional and modify your index action to conditionally use it, if it is passed in:

```
def index
  @monsters = Monster.find_by_category(params[:category]) if params[:category]
  @monsters ||= Monster.all
end
```

Comment: oh thank you! thats really handy. what about the link_to? should i still be using that or a form_tag?